# Amazon Kinesis + GNIP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, gnip

I'm using GNIP's PowerTrack feature to obtain tweets in real-time, i'm looking to connect the stream to a Kinesis stream. Has anyone tried this or know of any sample code that might help out? (Preferably PHP)

I've been playing around with both services but can't seem to understand how the Kinesis connection actually works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this ami.  It will connect to gnip. Then you just write a consumer. 
http://support.gnip.com/code/gnip-kinesis-ami.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it took them a few months to actually come out with the required scripts.

Comment: I believe gnip has to give you access to the ami.

Answer (score 0):

I think Robby already sent you a note a little while ago, but if not, we have some resources to share that will help with the connection from Gnip to Kinesis.  We'll send them your way.